# final variable in constructor with inherited call

Tags: java

I just discovered something quite weird. If a final variable is called from the implicit super constructor using an overriden method, the element will never not be initialiazed upon call :

```
public static abstract class A {

    public A() 
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    public abstract void doSomething();

}

public static class B extends A {

    private final Object s = new Object(); 

    public B()
    {
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    new B();// prints 'null'
}
```

If the method is not overriden, the final variable will be correctly instanciated :

```
public static class B  {

    private final Object s = new Object(); 

    public B()
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    new B(); // prints the object correctly
}
```

Finally, even stranger for me (i think this is relative to the String#intern mechanism)

```
public static abstract class A {

    public A() 
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    public abstract void doSomething();

}

public static class B extends A {

    private final String s = "Hello"; 

    public B()
    {
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    new B(); // will print "Hello"
}
```

My question is what can i do in the first case to fix this, should i use a getter that ensures non-null value ?

I sort of understand why the first case occurs (the constructor implicitely calls the 'super' constructor before initialization of any instance vars), but, if i am correct, in this case why is the 3rd case prints correctly 'Hello' ?

Comment: I believe the third case is basically an optimization due to it being initialized with a constant value. Try using `"Hello".toString()` and I think you'll see a different result. The "fix" is not to call non-final methods from constructors...

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a concrete example (real classes - not `A` and `B`) where this is an actual issue.

Comment: Well i have created those classes just after having a NPE  following a case in a real application

Comment: @JonSkeet - When would someone use `"Hello".toString()`?

Comment: To the answer that suggested `final` meant `constant` or even `compile time constant`, they're mistaken.

Comment: @TheLostMind: When they were trying to demonstrate the difference between a constant value and a nonconstant value :)

Comment: @JonSkeet The "fix" is not to call non-final methods from constructors... --> yes but in my case the call was made from a method called like the 3rd time from the constructor. So even if you call a final method from the constructor, it won't guarantee the code won't break.

Comment: Okay, to rephrase: don't all non-final methods during constructor execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that constructors of base classes are executed before constructors of subclasses. This means than fields of subclasses may not have been initialized during construction of base classes. (They *will* however be initialized during construction of the subclasses.)

> My question is what can i do in the first case to fix this, should i use a getter that ensures non-null value ?

The problem you've discovered is one of the reasons to never ever call overridable methods from within the constructor.

A getter is probably just as bad, since the getter would also be overridable.

Instead of having

```
Object s = new Object();

...

public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

in `B`, you can pass the variable to be used in the construction of `A` as an argument to `A`s constructor:

```
public B() {
    super(new Object());
}
```

This passes the data relevant for constructing the `B` object, so that the constructor of `B` is "self-contained". This is quite messy though, and I would advice you to reconsider the structure of your classes.

---

Regarding the third case:

```
private final String s = "Hello";
```

Since `"Hello"` is a compile time constant expression, and since `s` is final, the Java compiler is free to inline the use of `s`, i.e. replace `s` with `"Hello"` at it's discretion.

Comment: But that's just messy.

Comment: It may be worth elaborating on your final line. I've just checked, and it looks like the field really *isn't* initialized at the point of the call - but the Java compiler is inlining the value of `s` within the method call. I suspect that's what you mean, but more clarity would be good :)

Comment: @Qix, I agree. But I'd say it's inherent from the idea of letting subclasses affect construction of base classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet, out of curiosity, can C# also "inline" the use of compile time constant expressions. (Note, I have never written a line of C#.)

Comment: @aioobe: Yes, but an instance variable is never regarded as a compile-time constant, even if it is readonly, as it can have a new value assigned within the constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet - *it can have a new value assigned within the constructor* how come?.. It is marked `final` right?

Comment: @TheLostMind: in C#, as per the context of the comment.

Comment: I can of agree that the proposed solution is just a bit messy. Why would i need to delegate the object to the base class which should not even have any knowledge of it.

Comment: Well, in your original snippet you called `doSomething` (which is non-final) from the constructor of `A`, so in a sense *you* dictated that it should have (indirect) knowledge of the subclass.

Comment: @aioobe yes it has knowledge of the doSomething but not of what it does

Comment: Ok, so put it differently: By not making `doSomething` final (or private) you allowed subclasses to affect the construction of `A`. The (messy) workaround that I propose in my answer allows the subclass to affect the construction of `A`, but in a way that is explicit and let's the constructor of `A` execute in a self contained manner.

Comment: If you're not happy with the proposed workaround you could refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585424/alternatives-to-using-overridden-methods-in-constructors-java). If those answers aren't satisfactory either (I don't think any of those answers were spot on) you could set a bounty on it. I'm sure that would generate some good answers.